# Can I INDEX,Match,Search one cell for two separate lists and return the result that has both?

Tags: excel, search, indexing, match

### Backstory

I have been tasked with creating a system that fills in excel files for the user based on them entering minimal information. This includes categories, of which we have too many. I have a function that searches a cell for one list of criteria and returns the adjacent cells result. But with so many criteria there are often times where a wrong result is returned.

What I want to do is use a second criteria to make the search more specific.

### My current setup

The formula that I can currently using is:

`=INDEX(Categories!D$3:D$53,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Categories!C$3:C$53,I2)),0))`

So whatever the user enters into `I2` is cross-referenced with `Categories!C$3:C$53` and if there is a match then `Categories!D$3:D$53` is returned.

### Image

[image: Visiual Aid]

So you can see how its set up in the picture, purple is the second search criteria I'd like to add.

I did try to add a match function at the beginning so `IF` another cell = Cordless Power Tools then I could narrow down the search. But that would mean a separate formula for every category and sub-category of which there are hundreds.

Thank you for any help that you can be.

Edit - I have realised that what I want is actually much more complicated than I had originally thought.

What I want is to be able to search a cell for a match in column B and then if there is a match then only search that section in C to return adjacent value in D.

For example. I have a tool - an 18v 115mm Angle Grinder. So my search string is "18v 115mm Angle Grinder", The formula would then search this string for a match in column B which it does (B61) so then the formula would search for a match in "18v 115mm Angle Grinder" in only column C61 and C62, finding a match and returning "Grinders" from D61.

I realise this looks pointlessly complicated but there are hundreds of categories I'm trying to implement this in and there are simpler titles in all of them so I'm trying to narrow the search down so I don't have to use multiple formulas.

Thank again for any help anyone can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add another condition in the search, say, that column `A` matches what's entered by the user in `J2`, add the condition to your search using the `*` operator that applies a logical `And` on different conditions. But the only thing is that its result is a number 1/0 instead of True/False.

```
=INDEX(Categories!D$3:D$53,MATCH(1,
  ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Categories!C$3:C$53,I2))
  * (Categories!A$3:A$53 = J2)
  ,0))
```

p.s. dont forget to parenthesize the factors when using `*` as logical operator.

Comment: I assume the second condition here is a direct match? Can I not use another search function?

Comment: @RobL of course you can. Each individual condition can be a function on its own. But how could I guess what is the exact condition you want to add?

Comment: What you've suggested here is great but what I'm looking for is something like:

=INDEX(Categories!D$3:D$53,MATCH(1,
  ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Categories!C$3:C$53,I2))
  * (1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Categories!C$3:C$53,I2))
  ,0)))

I tried this but with no luck..

Comment: @Robl Try `=INDEX(Categories!D$3:D$53,MATCH(1, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Categories!C$3:C$53,I2)) * ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Categories!C$3:C$53,J2)) ,0))` . Each condition such as `IsNumber` is a factor inside the `MATCH`.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand how that works but it works and that's perfect. Thank you very much A.S.H